# Php: fetch record from database using calendar values

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I have a php file with username and password. When the user login the login information will be stored in login table as datetime format. (ex: 2010-05-21 15:05:55) and in the same way logout details will be stored. Now i would like to list the user information datewise. Hence, I use calendar function as

```
<body>
    <label>StartDate :&nbsp;</label><input name="startdate" type="text" onClick="displayDatePicker('startdate')">
    <label>EndDate :&nbsp;</label><input name="enddate" type="text" onClick="displayDatePicker1('enddate')">
</body>
```

Now my requirement is when the user chooses the from date and to date the login and logout informations on that particular date needs to be displayed in a table format. I tried something like

```
$start=$_POST['startdate']; 
$end=$_POST['enddate']; 
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE LoginTime = '$startdate' AND LogoutTime = '$enddate' ";
```

but it return null. Can u please tell me how to fetch record from database using the calendar values?

Comment: Dear @SmartWorker , please use it `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE LoginTime = '$startdate' AND LogoutTime = '$enddate' ") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @ÖmerASLAN i tried the above but still it returns null

Comment: Please check your php.ini file . You have to do something wrong. Then we want to see that error. OR your query is wrong because datetime format has hour:minute:second please check it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sql query

SELECT * FROM (LoginTime>=$startdate AND LoginTime<=$enddate) OR (LogoutTime>=$startdate AND LogoutTime<=$enddate)